# LWJGL - What to start writing?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Literally, what classes do I start out with writing? You start with the Display, right, with the screen and everything, but then what classes do you write? The main menu, or the maps? I'm just confused as to where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to start with writing the main game loop i.e: the update loop, which allows the Display to update itself.

You can probably start wherever you like though ;)

My self-rule is to start with the most important stuff.